# Get json data from Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am using the third party api for getting the Address on the basis of postcode . it returns the json data .
below is the api that i am calling but i am not sharing the datakey that i am using .

i am accessing this in jquery not using any server side scripting languages .

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.simplylookupadmin.co.uk/JSONservice/JSONSearchForAddress.aspx?datakey=data key &postcode=CM129BY&callback=?",           function () {
            alert("aaa");

                  });
```

also using the other code like

```
//          jQuery.ajax({
//              type: 'GET',
//              url: 'http://www.simplylookupadmin.co.uk/JSONservice/JSONSearchForAddress.aspx?datakey=data key&postcode=CM129BY?jsoncallback=?',
//              dataType: 'json',
//              success: function (data) {
//                  alert('success');
//              }
//          });
```

but i am getting the error

```
Error: invalid label
Source File: http://www.simplylookupadmin.co.uk/JSONservice/JSONSearchForAddress.aspx?datakey=datakey&postcode=CM129BY&callback=jQuery17209661092291729644_1335505434728&_=1335505437637
Line: 2, Column: 2
Source Code:
  "found":"1",
```

please advice its very urgent

Thanks
naveen Kumar GUpta.

Comment: what is "line 2 column 2" in this code?

Comment: its seems like a service specific error. are you getting this in all queries?

Comment: `datakey=data key ` ? There should be no spaces in that URL path.

Comment: Can you type the postal code URL into a browser address bar and tell us what you see?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing any Quotes.Please check it once again.

I think the postcode you are searching is not found in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
It is the JSON result string is invalid as JSON, open the URL [http://www.simplylookupadmin.co.uk/JSONservice/JSONSearchForAddress.aspx?datakey=data key &postcode=CM129BY&callback=?](http://www.simplylookupadmin.co.uk/JSONservice/JSONSearchForAddress.aspx?datakey=data%20key%20&postcode=CM129BY&callback=?) with web browser I got the content:

```
{
  "found":"1",
  "credits_display_text":"Cannot find FULL PAF license(credits or users)",
  "accountadminpage":"https://www.simplylookupadmin.co.uk/WebAccountLogin.aspx?doid=1&coid=30&Pay=yes",
  "errormessage":"Search denied! Cannot find FULL PAF license(credits or users)",
  "maxresults":"0",
  "recordcount":"0",
"records"]}
```

**At the end of it, "]" is not needed.**